# Vuejs: How to give the modal size according to a condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue modal implemented in a page. The size of the modal is lg or large. For a specific, if condition I want the size as lg , and for the else condition I want it as md. Is there a way to achieve this using vuejs properties.

```
<b-modal id="modal-1" size="lg">
  <upgrade-popup></upgrade-popup>
</b-modal>
```

I'am looking for way such as the one we use for conditional rendering of class

```
v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
```

Tried a condition like this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
:size="{'lg': freeUser, 'md': !freeUser}"
```

Comment: Would something like `:size="freeUser ? 'lg' : 'md'"` work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shorthand if

You can use a shorthand if `:size="freeUser ? 'lg' : 'md'"`
Using the shorthand, allows you to make a quick `if/else`, but is limited to that. but avoids a lot of extra markup.

---

#### Computed property

You can also use a computed property, which caches the value. and only recomputed when the internal properties used changes. In this case `freeUser`.

```html
<b-modal :size="getSize"></b-modal>


<script>
{
  computed: {
    getSize() {
      return this.freeUser ? 'lg' : 'md'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

#### Method

The method option allows you to handle more conditions easily, or more advanced cases, like the computed property. but unlike the computed property, methods allow you to pass in properties, which can be useful if you need to handle it based on content in a `v-for` for example.

```html
<b-modal :size="getSize(freeUser)"></b-modal>


<script>
{
  methods: {
    getSize(freeUser) {
      return this.freeUser ? 'lg' : 'md'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Or use computed if you want to update the size when `freeUser` value is changed.